# Plot ENU points on a map having an origin GPS Lat and Long

Tags: gps, coordinates

I have a GPS coordinate point to denote my origin:

```
8.6258,47.3325
```

Then I have a series of ENU (east, north up) points in meters that represent the distance from my origin:

```
-10, -1 //East, north (not using up)
-12, -2
-14, -3
-16, -5
....
```

I would like to plot this on a map, I know with google maps you can simply provide an array of coordinates and it builds it for you:

```
{[8.6258,47.3325],[8.6258,47.3325],[8.6258,47.3325]...}
```

I'm not sure how to convert those ENU points to coordinates. Any ideas?

Comment: What software, if any, do you have available or are familiar with? One solution would be to treat these coordinates as if they're in Orthographic or a "Local" (if using ArcGIS) with the center set to your origin. Unproject the points to get the lat/lon equivalents.

Comment: @mkennedy I can work with C, Java, Javascript... it's just a matter of figuring out the right algorithm I suppose.